# Is my proof that $\bigcup_{i\in I}(A_i \times B_i)\subseteq\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)\times\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i\right)$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This is my first time attempting to try to prove something pertaining to an indexed collection of sets. Is the proof that follows correct? I feel as if there's a fatal flaw.

Observation 1. Suppose $\{ A_i : i \in I \}$ and $\{ B_i : i \in I \}$ are indexed families of
sets, then $\bigcup _{i \in I} (A_i \times B_i) \subseteq  \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \times \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} B_i \right)$.

Proof. Let $(x, y)$ be arbitrary elements of $ \bigcup _{i \in I} (A_i \times B_i)$. Then $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$, and we have that $x \in A_i$ for some $i \in I$. Similarly, $y \in \bigcup_{i \in I} B_i$, and we have that $y \in B_i$ for some $i \in I$. So, $(x, y) \in \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \times \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} B_i \right)$. Since $(x, y)$ were arbitrary, then $\bigcup _{i \in I} (A_i \times B_i) \subseteq  \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \times \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} B_i \right)$.

Comment: Why is it the case that $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$? I ask because essentially this is the thesis you want to prove.

Comment: @Gae.S. Isn't it by the definition of the cartesian product? or can it not be that easily extended to a collection of sets? If A and B are sets, $A \times B$ implies that there are a pair of elements $(a, b)$ such that $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

Comment: You have to be a bit more careful about your notation though. If we would follow this argument with this notation in the other direction, one might believe that the other inclusion also holds (which it does not).

Comment: $x\in A\land y\in B$ implies $(x,y)\in A\times B$ by definition of $A\times B$, and therefore $x\in \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\land y\in\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$ implies $(x,y)\in\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)\times\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i\right)$. However, you have spent a lot of words into this passage, an no words at all in proving that $(x,y)\in\bigcup_{i\in I}(A_i\times B_i)$ implies $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ and $y\in\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$, which is essentially the beginning and the end of the proof.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the definitions in the wrong order. It's not that "$x\in A_i$ for some $i\in I$, and $y\in B_i$ for some $i\in I$", because that language indicates that the $i$ for $x$ and the $i$ for $y$ *may differ* (the context of the quantifier ends before the next one begins).

But let $X_i$ be $A_i\times B_i$, then you assume that $(x,y)\in\bigcup X_i$, so there is some $i\in I$ such that $(x,y)\in X_i$. In other words, there is some $i\in I$ such that $x\in A_i$ and $y\in B_i$. Here it is clear that this is the same $i$ for *both*.

Now we can move to the separate unions: $x\in A_i$, therefore $x\in\bigcup_{j\in I}A_j$, and $y\in B_i$ so $y\in\bigcup_{j\in I}B_j$. And so on.

Comment: Any actual critique on my answer would be most welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Most easy, imho, is to prove
$$A \times (B \cup C) = (A \times B) \cup (A \times C)$$
and then extend it .

Comment: How is this helpful?

Comment: In case $|I|=2, A_i=A$.

Comment: (1) Starting with a finite example "and extending it" will often give the impression that induction is needed (because these sort of statements are a fertile ground for examples of induction, even though they should not be proved by induction to begin with); (2) this is too much of a degenerate case, and may give the impression that equality is somehow expected in the general case, it is not; (3) how does it help the OP find the problems with their solution and learn from *their* mistakes?

Comment: (1) Starting with a finite example "and extending it"  often works also and in fail give more good understanding of question. This idea also gives answer for (2) and (3): It is good to see what works in easy case and what not work in general case. Working firstly in easy case gives personal skills and experience, which can be used as to find and elaborate mistakes, so looking deeply in question. It's well known general pedagogical method: first easy, then hard.